Movie where everything turns out to be the test of new VR glasses in helicopter
The movie was probably made somewhere after 2010 in Hollywood. According to what I remember, it had rather contemporary visual effects and overall visuals.
The plot begins with CEO of some company ready to depart in a helicopter, and a few employees approaching him, begging to find just a couple minutes to test VR glasses they have just made. Reluctantly, CEO agrees and puts glasses on. He then experiences a chain of events, where he constantly tries to avoid assassinations, faces betrayals, etc.
In the end it turns out that everything was a virtual reality in the VR glasses, and he finally wakes up in helicopter when employees take the glasses off him.
Sorry if I remember some of the details wrong, it's been a few years since I saw the movie.

After another half hour of Googling, I found it.
The Illusion of Control (2022)

Entire life Victor perfectly manipulated others in his own interests. This allowed him to control large financial flows. Once, he discovered that since childhood he was a puppet in someone's game. Trying to find out who's behind this all, Victor reveals new, difficult to recognize, technologies of influencing the consciousness of a modern man.

Trailer



